# Can't close a tkinter window

Tags: python, forms, tkinter

If i run it it will open the blue window but `destroy()` will not close the window. How can i fix it with a commant that closes it?
Internet resources point to the `destroy()` comand which doesnt function.

Although i know that `mainloop` keeps the window alive when i try to exit it using `destroy`it just doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


my_window = Tk()
my_window.title('Lang')
my_window.configure(background= 'blue')
#time.sleep(1)
my_window.mainloop()

my_window.withdraw()
my_window.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the mainloop at the end of your code.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


my_window = Tk()
my_window.title('Lang')
my_window.configure(background= 'blue')
#time.sleep(1)

my_window.withdraw()
my_window.destroy()

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `my_window.mainloop` must be always at the end. Is that it?